# How to avoid page flicker in JSF 1.1 + Ajax4jsf?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I am developing a small application usng JSF 1.1, Ajax4jsf and Tiles. When I click the `a4j:commandLink`, the entire page is reloaded. I want to update only portion of the page. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Get greeting" reRender="greeting" />
```

You must to use the property reRender to update some section of your page.
For more information, see [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandLink.html).